# Как в Gtk4 получить уведомление об изменении размера виджета?

Tags: gtk, vala, gtk4

Пытаюсь переписать свое старое приложение для просмотра картинок с `Gtk3` на `Gtk4`.
Если раньше можно было спокойно подключиться к сигналу `size_allocate`, то в `gtk4` этот сигнал удалили и теперь я не могу понять как узнать когда у виджета меняются размеры.

Comment: [смотрел уже](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/stable/ch41s02.html#id-1.7.4.4.39)? если картинки рисуются на GtkDrawingArea, то рекомендуют использовать сигнал `resize`... иначе — событие ресайза окна...

Comment: Видел, но там не ничего полезного. Если у виджета подключиться к сигналу `notify`, там нет сообщений об изменении размера. Конечно есть большая вероятность что я туплю и на самом деле все просто.
ЗЫ: попробую тогда просто на размер окна смотреть.

Comment: нум... как написано в [коммите](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/commit/56e590bd3147cdb3211fbe61d1f4cad7a392fffa), девы считают, что использовать `size_allocate` неправильно, поэтому они решили его удалить... для общего случая простой альтернативы я не вижу, так что скорей всего придётся придумывать что-то конкретно под свою задачу...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После некоторых экспериментов, я нашел решение которое меня устраивает.
Возможно есть более красивые варианты, но я их не знаю.

```
class MyAppWindow: Gtk.ApplicationWindow {

    public int windowWidth {
        get { return get_width(); }
        set {
            Idle.add(() => {
                print(@"window width: $value\n");
                return Source.REMOVE;
            });
        }
    }

    public bool isMaximized {
        get { return maximized; }
        set {
            Idle.add(() => {
                print(@"window maximized: $isMaximized; width: $(get_width())\n");
                return Source.REMOVE;
            });
        }
    }

    public MyAppWindow(Gtk.Application app) {
        Object(application: app);
        this.bind_property("default-width", this, "windowWidth", BindingFlags.DEFAULT | BindingFlags.SYNC_CREATE);
        this.bind_property("maximized", this, "isMaximized", BindingFlags.DEFAULT | BindingFlags.SYNC_CREATE);
    }
}
```

Здесь я свойства `default_width` и `maximized` которые есть в `Gtk.ApplicationWindow` подключаю к свойствам `windowWidth` и `isMaximized`.

При обычном растягивании окна вызывается `setter` в `windowWidth`, где мы можем вызвать сигнал или другой метод.
`isMaximized` сработает только при максимизации окна и это нужно для получения размера окна т.к. в этом случаее `windowWidth` не сработает.

В `Gtk.Widget` подобное у меня не получилось сделать, но можно попробовать реализовать методы `measure`, `size_allocate`, `get_request_mode` и в `size_allocate` перехватывать изменения размера виджета.

В Gtk4 добавили бредовые `LayoutManager`, хотя может они и полезны, но мне пока только мешают.
Если в виджет добавить `LayoutManager`, то методы `measure`, `size_allocate`, `get_request_mode` которые вы переопределите в классе виджета не будут вызываться.